# JUnit Test Class template not converted to Kotlin file in Kotlin project

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, junit

If I open a Kotlin project and try to create my own template for JUnit Test Classes I get the generated template generated as a Java file instead of as a Kotlin file.

Is there any way to make this generation to happen as a Kotlin file?

I attached some images to easily show the issue I am facing.

The question marks on one of the images have to do because I don't know what that default parse function does. I tried to change it to `#parse("File Header.kt")` but that does not work.

[image: File template]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was trying to add kotlin code to the template.

All I had to do is create the template using Java code and it automatically gets generated in Java.

However, if anyone know a way to specifically use this feature using your own kotlin code instead of generated one, please let me know.